# Select a specific TukeyHSD plot

Tags: plot, posthoc

Is there a way to select a specific TukeyHSD plot in a similar way that you can select a specific diagnostic plot for a `lm()` model using the `which =` argument in `plot()`? I'm trying to resize the last plot to be much bigger because there are so many pairwise comparisons, but I want the first two plots to be the default size.

My code right now:

```
{r fig.height=14, fig.width=20}
par(cex.axis = 0.9, mar = c(5, 7, 3, 5))
plot(TukeyHSD(islands_initial_aov), las = 1, cex = 0.5)
```

I'm using a R markdown file and not a script in case that is helpful.